# How to add clienttemplate.js to schema.xml for a SharePoint list using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, quick-edit

Can anyone suggest me a code to do the following 2 changes in the `Schema.Xml` of a list:

1) To change the Type from **HTML** to **GRID**.

2) To add the following JSLink:

```
<JSLink>clienttemplate.js<\JSLink>
```

We do not have access to Visual Studio and SharePoint designer. So is there any way to update and add this line of code to the `Schema.xml` through PowerShell?

**[image: PowerShell]**

Thanks in Advance.